# Godot 4 NavigationAgent2D and CharacterBody 2D

Tags: godot, gdscript

My swordsmen cannot bypass a shield bearer because the shield bearer is not considered a barrier by the swordsmen and therefore they go through him. Swordsmen need to bypass the shortest path to such objects that interfere with their movement .How to fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqaxt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8aM7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lir16.png)

I tried using NavigationObstacles2D but either I didn't configure it correctly or something else but it didn't help and when I read the documentation for NavigationObstacles2D it was said that it is better not to use it for non-static objects